# Which version of ThreeJS do I need for my object-loader to work?

Tags: three.js

I created a little 3d-model in Spline, and I exported it to web. I know that the scene.json can be loaded through the Object-Loader but I am not sure which version of Threejs is compatible.
The metadata of the object is this:

```
{
    "version": 1.5,
    "type": "Object",
    "generator": "Object3D.toJSON"
}
```

I tried the newest version of threejs and it doesn’t work, is there a correct version?

##### The error message I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: I know its cliched, but what have you tried? There's no code here, so it's hard to say where it goes wrong. As far as I know, the ObjectLoader is not included by default in THREE.js - they are separate imports in the examples folder (weird, yeah, I know). You should just use the one that came with the version of threejs you are using and it should work fine.

Comment: @somethinghere This is the error that I am getting: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/831810466006827048/916346554871345212/unknown.png

Comment: Shouldnt you use any loaders ‘load’ or ‘loadAsync’ method? Parsing is a method for internal use in the loader mostly?

Comment: @somethinghere In the docs it says that the parse method can be used if you already have the json-object on hand, as a variable.

Comment: @somethinghere When I try .load() this happens: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/831810466006827048/916358879166742538/unknown.png

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to load your data? You should also include what's in the `splineElement` object after it's loaded. Maybe you could do `console.log(splineElement)` and show us your console output. My guess is that it doesn't contain the necessary data for the `.parse()` method to understand.